How to check which enum values are set based on a combined value
I am having 5 checkboxes.
public enum animals : int
{
    Cat      = 1
    ,Dog     = 2
    ,Mouse   = 3
    ,Rat     = 4
    ,Lizzard = 5
}

On saving my window I can sum up they checkboxes that are checked, in int res_flags and save it.
int res_flags = 0;

if ((bool)this.chbCat.IsChecked)        res_flags |= (int)animals.Cat;
if ((bool)this.chbDog.IsChecked)        res_flags |= (int)animals.Dog;
if ((bool)this.chbMouse.IsChecked)      res_flags |= (int)animals.Mouse;
if ((bool)this.chbRat.IsChecked)        res_flags |= (int)animals.Rat;
if ((bool)this.chbLizzard.IsChecked)    res_flags |= (int)animals.Lizzard;

How can I check at the start which were checked based on the int res_flags?

Assuming you want this to work like [Flags], each enum case should have an int value that is a power of 2. Then you can use e.g. res_flags.HasFlag(animals.Cat) to check.

Assume that Cat (1 = 0b0001) and Dog (2 = 0b0010) are set, you get 0b0011 = 3 which is the same as Mouse. Therefore you need powers of 2 having always exactly one bit set when using enums as flags.

Just in case you did want to count the flags, you can do that better than testing each flag individually with BitOperations.PopCount.

So if I have to return a int value for the checkboxes, my only option is to change the enums to 0001,0002,0004,0008,0016 cause the cant collide, right?

@Philipp yes. Values which are not powers of 2 will colide in the bit-level and you will not be able to distinguish which values were combined.

@user555045 I editted the title because it was quite clear from the body of the question that the OP needs to know which values were combined (and not how many). I hope you agree with my understanding.


How can I check at the start which were checked based on the int res_flags?

In this case it is very convenient to add the [Flags] attribute to the enum, and make the values powers of 2. It's easy to make sure the values are powers of 2 by using bit-shift operator<< with an increasing value.
Then you can use Enum.HasFlag to check if a specific flag is set:
[Flags]
public enum animals : int
{
    Cat = 1 << 0,
    Dog = 1 << 1,
    Mouse = 1 << 2,
    Rat = 1 << 3,
    Lizzard = 1 << 4
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    animals res_flags = animals.Cat | animals.Dog;

    Console.WriteLine(res_flags.HasFlag(animals.Cat));
    Console.WriteLine(res_flags.HasFlag(animals.Dog));
    Console.WriteLine(res_flags.HasFlag(animals.Mouse));
    Console.WriteLine(res_flags.HasFlag(animals.Rat));
    Console.WriteLine(res_flags.HasFlag(animals.Lizzard));
}

Output:
True
True
False
False
False

Live demo
Note that res_flags is no longer of type int, but rather of the enum type animals.
